My pallet fails to compile in runtime because of RuntimeEvent and RuntimeCall
I am trying to update my Pallet to latest PolkadotSDK version and while I have RuntimeEvent configured in same way as Template Pallet it still fails in my pallet for some reason. Am I missing something?
Here are error messages:
>   error[E0277]: the trait bound `RuntimeEvent:
> From<pallet_parachain_xnft::Event<Runtime>>` is not satisfied
>      --> /GitHub/polkadot-sdk/templates/parachain/runtime/src/configs/mod.rs:315:22
>       |   315 |     type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
>       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<pallet_parachain_xnft::Event<Runtime>>` is not implemented for
> `RuntimeEvent`
>       |
>       = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<cumulus_pallet_xcm::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<frame_system::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<pallet_balances::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<pallet_collator_selection::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<pallet_message_queue::Event<Runtime>>`
>                 `RuntimeEvent` implements `From<pallet_parachain_template::Event<Runtime>>`
>               and 4 others   note: required by a bound in `pallet_parachain_xnft::Config::RuntimeEvent`
>      --> /GitHub/polkadot-sdk/templates/parachain/pallets/xnft/src/lib.rs:47:22
>       |   47  |         type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
>       |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Config::RuntimeEvent`
> 
>   error[E0277]: the trait bound `RuntimeCall:
> From<pallet_parachain_xnft::Call<Runtime>>` is not satisfied
>      --> /GitHub/polkadot-sdk/templates/parachain/runtime/src/configs/mod.rs:323:21
>       |   323 |     type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
>       |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<pallet_parachain_xnft::Call<Runtime>>` is not implemented for
> `RuntimeCall`
>       |
>       = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<cumulus_pallet_xcm::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<frame_system::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<pallet_collator_selection::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<pallet_message_queue::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>                 `RuntimeCall` implements `From<<pallet_parachain_template::Pallet<Runtime> as
> Callable<Runtime>>::RuntimeCall>`
>               and 5 others   note: required by a bound in `pallet_parachain_xnft::Config::RuntimeCall`
>      --> /GitHub/polkadot-sdk/templates/parachain/pallets/xnft/src/lib.rs:69:21
>       |   69  |         type RuntimeCall: From<Call<Self>> + Encode;
>       |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Config::RuntimeCall`
> 
>   For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.

Here is my pallet configuration of event and call:
type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>; 
type RuntimeCall: From<Call<Self>> + Encode;

This is how they are imported to Runtime mod.rs:
impl pallet_parachain_xnft::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
}


This:
>       |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<pallet_parachain_xnft::Event<Runtime>>` is not implemented for
> `RuntimeEvent`

and this:
^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<pallet_parachain_xnft::Call<Runtime>>` is not implemented for
> `RuntimeCall`

Seem to indicate that you didn't add your pallet to construct_runtime or that you have not added Call and Event to the list of exported types of the pallet.
